# Save input on cache when button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a part of my html:

```
 <p>City: <input type="text" id=city value="New York"> </p>
<p>State: <input type="text" id=state value="NY"> </p>
<button id="search">Search!</button>
<button id="favorite">mark as favorite!</button>
```

Bellow is my .js

The search function is working like a charm, it does an ajax call with the inputs and receive weather infos.

my problem is with the favorite button, what i need is to search for example Baltimore and click on Mark as favorite. This will make Baltimore to be the one to opens when I refresh the page. 
I believe that one alternative would be changing the standard input text because my ajax call is made when document its ready or when search button is clicked but i have no idea how to do it yet.

```
     $('#search').click(function() {
            ajax();
 });


     $('#favorite').click(function() {
         var $city= $('#city')
         document.getElementById('city').value= $city.val(); 
     });
```

any ideas??

edit: solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $city= $('#city')
    document.getElementById("city").value = localStorage.getItem("city");

    ajax();

});

...
...
...

     $('#favorite').click(function() {
                var $city = $('#city')
            // Check browser support
             if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                 // Store
                 localStorage.setItem("city", $city.val() );
                 // Retrieve
                 document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("city");
             } else {
                 document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = "not possible to store";
             }

                ajax();
```

Comment: You can use localStorage...or something like: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I'm an industrial engineer learning this programming stuff as a hobby for the last 2 months so thanks Hackerman for the help and your post was useless mr Duncan.

Comment: ps: found a easy solution with localStorage, its on the code